# images saved to desktop overwriting previous image

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, screenshot

I added a function to my JSP web app where the user can take a screenshot of the page he is viewing and saves the image to the desktop when I take another screenshot, it overwrites the previous image. is there any way I can increment so it will save as image, and if I take another screenshot, it will save as image1, image2, etc.

The code that is performing this task is

```
try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        BufferedImage screenShot = robot
                .createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
        String home = System.getProperty("user.home");

        ImageIO.write(screenShot, "JPG", new File(home + "\\Desktop\\i.jpg"));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you will first need to check if there is already a file with that same name in the desktop:

```java
boolean check = new File(directory, temp).exists();
```

If the booelan check is true, it means that the file already exists, with the same name. You will then change the second file's name as you prefer (for example, by adding a number to it)!

Also, if the user wants to save the file as *image3* and there already is a file called that way, you can change it like this:

```java
int num;

try {
   num = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(string.substring(string.length() - 1)));
   // then change the name of the file that you are saving for example, from "image4" to "image5"
} catch (exception e) {
   // This means that the name of the file you are saving does not finish with a number, so you can simply proceed by adding a "1" as the last character of the string name (containing the name of the file the user wants to save)
}
```